# JavaScript module keyword

Tags: javascript, module

I'm working through Kyle Simpson's "You Don't Know JavaScript" series. At the end of (published 2014) "Scope & Closures" (p. 62), there is an example in ES6 of using the keyword "module" to import an entire module, like so:

```
// import the entire "foo" and "bar" modules
module foo from "foo";
module bar from "bar";

console.log(
    bar.hello( "rhino" )    
); 

foo.awesome();
```

This code doesn't work, however. My question is: is the `module` keyword something that was experimented with and dropped? Should I forget about this keyword?

Answer (score 5):

They're typos

```
// import the entire "foo" and "bar" modules
import foo from "foo";  //fixed
import bar from "bar";  //fixed

console.log(
    bar.hello( "rhino" )    
); 

foo.awesome();
```

Sometimes, the examples in a book are not 100% accurate in typo, they really make confusion for the beginners.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a typo, though. Here is the paragraph that follows: "_import_ imports one or more members from a modul's API into the current scope... _module_ imports an entire module API to a bound variable..." This book was published in 2014. It feels like this was the proposed way to do it (in 2014), and they went with _import_ only.

Comment: @zumafra you're right, I've re-read that book and I have to tell that, there's must be something wrong and the author's not always correct in everything. Btw, in order to import `an entire module API to a bound variable`, you could do so: `import * as foo from 'foo'`. Moreover, the way the author using `export` is also someway incorrect.

Comment: @zumafra You might notice that, this book is written and published in 2014 while the `import/export` syntax is officially available at ES2015 which means, the author just wrote this book based on a draft of ES2015, not the official one. And you might also notice that, the title of that section is `Future Modules` which discuss about the future of module management system in Javascript.